# Проблема с url: наращивание ccылки

Tags: url, global-variables, php

Проблема вот такого рода.

у меня есть `_GET` параметр `locale=ru` и ссылка `index.php?post=123`, а также есть другая ссылка домой `Index.php` как мне применить _GET параметр ко второй ссылки или первой ссылке? 
я понимаю что сперва нужен вот этот символ &, а во втором случае нужен вот этот ? как определить точно когда какой нужен символ.

`REQUEST_URI` или `PHP_SELF` не работаю, как как нужен параметер который возможно находиться в `URL`, C `REQUEST_URI` проблема возникает в том, что он начинает наращивать ccылку и получается так `?p=1&p=2&p=3&locale=ru` с `PHP_SELF` подругому он не определяет если есть уже ссылка например `?action=view&` он выводит это `?locale=ru`

Comment: Ничего не понял со сказанного, какая цель у всего этого лучше объясните, а мы подумаем как это лучше реализовать.

Comment: Чтобы URL не "наращивался", используйте $_POST параметр или, что предпочтительнее, $_COOKIE.

Comment: @VenZell, кука хуже - она на каждый запрос будет отсылаться, особо это плохо, в случае если assets на том-же домене. Вообще в куку ничего кроме сессии складывать нежелательно.

Comment: @eicto, мне не хватает опыта, чтобы подискутировать на эту тему, но чем кука хуже, если она используется для определения языка?

Comment: тем, что ее браузер посылает каждый раз. Даже когда не надо, ведь там где локаль, там и другие параметры захочется хранить (а что ? удобно!) :)

Comment: Как объяснить ссылке что помимо переменной Locale=ru есть еще p=1 или нету p=1 или какой то другого параметра. Понятно, что для первого параметра ставиться ?, а для всех остальных &. в том числе нужно учитывать _GET или _POST параметры. я написал скрипт но он не работает. Решение нашел в том, чтобы указывать параметр в каждом файле.

Answer (score 3):

```
$mystring = 'url';
$findme   = '?';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if($pos === false){
echo '? нет';
}else{
echo '? есть';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка формируется следующим образом:

http://domen.com/путь/к/твоему/файлу.php? -< знак вопроса указывает на то что дальше идут параметры, и потом все параметры должны быть в таком формате:

`ключ=значение`

что бы разделять пары ключ-значение используют `&`

и того ссылка с несколькими параметрами будет выглядеть так:

`http://domen.com/путь/к/твоему/файлу.php?locale=ru&post=123`

порядок следования пар ключ-значение не имеет значение.

> > переименную подругому как разложить весь REQUEST_URI на переменные с их именнами?

что бы получить значение переменной из url - есть суперглобальные переменные:

- $_GET (если запрос страници произошел методом GET)
- $_POST (если запрос страници произошел методом POST)
- $_REQUEST (если всё равно)

итого:

что бы получить переменые из текущего запроса:

$_REQUEST['locale'] и $_REQUEST['post']

Comment: в этом ответе не хватает только упоминание функции http_build_query

Comment: я знаю мне нужно не это.

Comment: переименную подругому как разложить весь REQUEST_URI на переменные с их именнами?

Comment: добавил ответ. Не нужно ничего разлаживать, всё уже разложено :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем я написал вот такой вот небольшой скрипт, работает, но подглючивает не пойму где.

```
function url_decoder($stringurl = ""){

$urlstring = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(strpos($urlstring, '?') === false){
    return $result = "?".$stringurl;
}else{

    $result = '?'.$stringurl;

    // it's p (page listing) fix
    if(!empty($_GET)){
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            if($key != strstr($stringurl, "=", true)){
                $replaced_urls = "&".$key."=".$value;
            }else
                $replaced_urls = null;

            $result .= $replaced_urls; 
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

Comment: я просто оставлю это здесь  
http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php  
http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php